# The baking process was not completed properly. There are black areas

Tags: texture-baking, uv-image-editor, normal-map

I encountered an error in the 'Baking' process as in the image. I did 'normal map' and 'diffuse' operations. The neck, around the eyes and some parts of your body are black. How can I fix these areas.
[image]
[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You probably have overlapping UVs or other problems in your UV map. Fixing the UV map should be the solution here.

Comment: hello i am adding uv map. Is this map a problem? Can you check?